# apache ignite fetches time as 1970-01-01 value from php pdo_odbc sql query

Tags: h2, ignite, pdo-odbc

I have loaded data into ignite cache using php pdo_odbc driver sql query.

If I query data using ignite rest api, I can see the all data fields correctly. Time field is displayed 10:20:00 which is correct.

But when I select it from php, time field (java.sql.Time) field is displayed as 1907-01-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time type is not currently supported by Apache Ignite ODBC.

Comment: It is going to be supported in 2.0 though - [IGNITE-4690](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4690), [IGNITE-4691](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4691)